# Not changing database value for file upload if blank?

Tags: php

I know that this code below work perfectly, I already tried it and it worked fine for one input type "file", but what if I have 7 inputs type "file"? how to check if one of them is empty or all of them are empty to not upload blank values to the database? thanks in advance.

```
if ((!($_FILES['image']['name']))) /* If there Is No file Selected*/ {

"Upload SQL status"

} else /* If file is  Selected*/ {

"Upload SQL status"

$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($img,"images/$image");
}
```

---

**Such as:**

```
<input  type="file" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png" 
 name="image1" />


<input  type="file" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png" 
 name="image2" />


<input  type="file" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png" 
 name="image3" />


<input  type="file" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png" 
 name="image4" />


<input  type="file" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png" 
 name="image5" />


<input  type="file" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png" 
 name="image6" />


<input  type="file" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png" 
 name="image7" />
```

---

**Getting the image from the field:**

```
    //getting the image from the field
    $image1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];


    //getting the image from the field
    $image2 = $_FILES['image2']['name'];


    //getting the image from the field
    $image3 = $_FILES['image3']['name'];


    //getting the image from the field
    $image4 = $_FILES['image4']['name'];


    //getting the image from the field
    $image5 = $_FILES['image5']['name'];

    //getting the image from the field
    $image6 = $_FILES['image6']['name'];

    //getting the image from the field
    $image7 = $_FILES['image7']['name'];
```

---

**After click update, I want my other fields also to be updated in the database like this:**

```
$update_restaurant = "update restaurants set 
restaurant_name='$name',restaurant_time='$time', 
area='$area',cuisine='$cuis',header='$header', 
Overview='$overview',Menu='$menu',website='$wb', 
facebook='$fb',meals='$meals',payment='$pay', phone='$phone' , 
map='$map_link', maptext='$map_des', img1='$image1', img2='$image2', 
img3='$image3', img4='$image4',img5='$image5', img6='$image6', 
img7='$image7', mapid='$map_id' where restaurant_id='$update_id'";
```

---

Thanks.

Comment: instead of `name="image1"` use `name="image[]"`for all 7 then loop the array

Comment: Ok great I will try it but how to add each picture in their specific column in the database table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `name="image[]"` instead of `name="image1"`, `name="image2"` etc.

Then, you can iterate with field like follows:

```
foreach($_FILES['image'] as $file) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($file)) {
        // file was uploaded - do something

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, greatttt, I will try this out but how the database will add each picture in their specific column in the table since they all have the same name? I edited my code in my question to check it out. Thank you so much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You're updating a single row in your database, you should probably be inserting each image as a *new* row.

e.g.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into restaurants set restaurant_name=:name, filename=:name, ...");
$stmt->execute([$restaurantName, $img1]);
```

([standard injection warning applies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/65387))

Any time you have column names like img1, img2, img3... you're probably doing something wrong. Even *two* repeated columns like phone1 and phone2 is probably going to come back to bite you sooner or later when some special snowflake client decides they really, really, really need a 3rd phone number.